# Is it posible to get the current location in Android MapView without using Location Listener?

Tags: android

I have a MapView application. When application launches it should show the current location. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public class MyLocationOnMap extends MapActivity {

       private LocationManager hdLocMgr;
       private String hdLocProvider;


       onCreate(...) {
            :
         Criteria hdCrit = new Criteria();
         hdCrit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
         hdCrit.setAltitudeRequired(false);
         hdCrit.setBearingRequired(false);
         hdCrit.setCostAllowed(true);
         hdCrit.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

         hdLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

         hdLocProvider = hdLocMgr.getBestProvider(hdCrit, true); 

         Location location = hdLocMgr.getLastKnownLocation(hdLocProvider);

         Double dlat = location.getLatitude();
         Double dlon = location.getLongitude();
                 :
       }

}
```

Comment: can I get the current location in emulator?

Comment: yes you can - go to http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html  and search for "Setting the location of the phone"

Answer (score 1):

Using the Location Manager, you can : Obtain your current location

Selecting a location provider

```
String providerName = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
LocationProvider gpsProvider;
gpsProvider = locationManager.getProvider(providerName);
```

Finding Location Providers Using Criteria

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
Criteria.setCostAllowed(true);

String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

Location location =
      locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    updateWithNewLocation(location);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider , 2000, 10,
            locationListener);
```

For details Visit : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

Comment: yeh, seems that alot of idiots like to give rubbish answer without even reading comments