# How to send my location (longitude and latitude) as a reply sms to other person?

Tags: java, android, gps, sms

I have an application in which I need to send my location(longitude and latitude ) to other person on receiving a sms from him.I'll somehow get my location(longitude and latitude) and put it as a text in reply sms and then send it to other person.But now I'm facing a problem in how to get my location and put it as a text in reply sms.Till now I have written a code which sends a reply message on receiving a sms from other person.Can anyone tell me how to get my location and put it as text message?

Here is my code to send reply message:

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

```
    Intent m=new Intent(context, ReceivelocationActivity.class);    
      PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, m, 0); 
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = ""; 
    String str2="";
    String str3="";
    String autoReplyToken = "Request_Accepted";
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
            str2=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
         str3=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";        
        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        boolean isAutoReply = str3.startsWith(autoReplyToken);
         /* As suggested by Dan J   */
 Criteria hdCrit = new Criteria();
 hdCrit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
 hdCrit.setAltitudeRequired(false);
 hdCrit.setBearingRequired(false);
 hdCrit.setCostAllowed(true);
 hdCrit.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

 hdLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

 hdLocProvider = hdLocMgr.getBestProvider(hdCrit, true); 

 Location location = hdLocMgr.getLastKnownLocation(hdLocProvider);

 Double dlat = location.getLatitude();
 Double dlon = location.getLongitude();

        String msg = dlat + "," + dlon ;
/*  As suggested by Dan J  */ 
        if (!isAutoReply) {
            String autoReplyText = autoReplyToken + msg;
            sms.sendTextMessage(str2, null, autoReplyText, pi, null);
        }

    }                 
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to send actual location in "msg" variable instead of string "location".Anyone with any idea please let me know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even I want to know the answer for this question,let's see if there is anyone out there more experienced who can come to rescue.

Comment: have you figured out how to get location yet? after this you can just pass in the numbers you get from the location object http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Comment: I tried it as suggested by Dan J and made appropriate additions in my code but now it is not even compiling.If you have any idea what is going wron please suggest me ?

Comment: You are going to have to tell us the compile error if you want help fixing it!  Have you imported all the classes you need?  If you are using Eclipse let it fix the imports for you (press Ctrl + Shift + o).

Comment: @Dan J : I think OP has mentioned the error below your answer.Check that comment below your answer."It is showing error on this line hdLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); it is saying create method getSystemService() ." as said by OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241384/is-it-posible-to-get-the-current-location-in-android-mapview-without-using-locat/5241731#5241731) for how to get the longitude and latitude:

Then just change

```
String msg = "location" ;
```

to

```
String msg = dlat + ", " + dlon;
```

You'll also need to add the appropriate permissions to your manifest XML (e.g. see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946035/android-locationmanager-not-calling-methods/7947479#7947479)).

Comment: I have added that piece of code in my existing code,you can see it in comments /* As suggested by Dan J */ but it is not compiling.It is showing error on this line  hdLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  it is saying create method getSystemService() . Am I doing anything wrong here.Please correct me where I'm wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try calling context.getSystemService() instead.  Solving compile errors should be pretty easy - if the compiler can't find the method, then you need to find out what Object offers that method (just Google it), and call the method on that Object. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html